# Cannot access mysql on ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying get my first simple project in rails to run. I have installed wamp. And trying to make use of that same mysql db server installed with wamp. But I decided to make use of webrick, and not apache. Hoping that the configuration would be easier.
I edited the database.yml file and the gemfile under my projects directory:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql2
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rubybeg_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rubybeg_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rubybeg_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
```

And here's gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'

# end
```

I used the command gem install mysql because mysql2 doesn't work for me.

[image]

What I did was to launch wampserver and stopped the apache service. It would take forever to load:
http://localhost:3000/rails/info/properties
Then webrick would crash. But if I do not launch wamp, I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure mysql to run on a port other than 3306?  If you're using a different port than that, you'll need to edit as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rubybeg_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
  port: 3306 #replace with the correct port
```

If that doesn't work, also try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in order to force it to use TCP.  Sometimes it tries to use sockets and cannot find the socket file.